# How to change screen layout according to the orientation?

Tags: android, android-layout

in portrait i have 5 icons. 4 icons in the first row,and 1 icon in the second row. but in landscape the 5th icon has to fit in the first row.   how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: u are arranged that icons in any grid layout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use different layout files for portrait and landscape positions.
use `layout-land` for landscape positions. Android will automatically select your landscape layout when the orientation changes.

Comment: How would you do so if your handling configChanges yourself?

Answer (score 3):

For this u take one linear lay out and set how many icons in that and again take one more linear lay out and set the icons for that.This is one way and other way is create a folder name as layout-land and add that layout file(main .xml) in this and arrange in this what ever u want.Layout-land automatically takes that file when device orientation is changed.

layout ----- Portrait

layout-land-------Landscape

Answer (score 1):

Apply the code in oncreate() mwthod

```
 if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
 {
    // do code here to arrange the layout as for portrait mode
 }
 else
 {
    // do code here to arrange the layout as for Landscape mode   
 }
```

each time on orientation change this will be called then generate view accrodingly

Answer (score 0):

use layout-land and Don't use android:configChanges="orientation" in your manifest.