# Rotating device won't load the land or port layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, rotation, listactivity

I've a class `MyClass` that extends `ListActivity`.
The list use 2 different xml for every row, depending to the device orientation:

```
layout-land/row_layout.xml
layout-port/row_layout.xml
```

I want that if the device is vertical the list will show the xml layout in the folder layout-port and if the device is horizontal the list will show the xml layout in the folder layout-land.

But this doesn't happen. My activity will always show `layout-port/row_layout.xml`, also after that I rotate the device from vertical to horizontal.

Should I use a particular method triggered on rotating device?

Comment: `layout-port` should simply be called `layout` afaik.

Comment: In fact - there are some useful tips in this stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920810/how-to-change-screen-layout-according-to-the-orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think to one thing at this moment. Are you using android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" in the manifest for that activity to avoid recreation of the list/adapter ?

Comment: Yes, I use: android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

Comment: If you remove it, then your activity will be recreated with the proper port/land layout, but you have to manage to save the displayed data and reload it when the config change is done.

Comment: Oh my God. All this work? :( Do you have an example or a link to?

Comment: Is there the possibilty, in xml, to tell: "if portrait then width=50sp else if landscape then width=100sp"? Just to avoid all the management via code!

Comment: No, but you can tell it from code, checking the device orientation and so on, but the best and cleanest way to do properly. Maybe this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915952/how-to-save-state-during-orientation-change-in-android-if-the-state-is-made-of-m